# "Variable must be initialized" error when delegating to an initialized property

Tags: kotlin

```
object Foo : CharSequence by Foo.X {
    val X = ""
}
```

produces

```
Variable 'X' must be initialized
```

But it is! And the code should translate to something like

```
object Foo : CharSequence {
    val X = ""
    override val length get() = Foo.X.length
    override operator fun get(index: Int): Char = Foo.X[index]
    override fun subSequence(startIndex: Int, endIndex: Int) = Foo.X.subSequence(startIndex, endIndex)
}
```

which works well.

What is the reason for the error and is there a workaround? In real code initialization is non-trivial and `Foo` needs to be an `object` (actually, a companion object), not a `class`.

Answer (score 1):

I speculate that using class delegation on an object is a bit non-obvious, so that's probably the essence of *why*.

A workaround is to delegate directly to an instance of String. This code works for me:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("Hello, world! ${Bar.Foo.indexOf("z")}") // Prints "2"
}

class Bar {
  companion object Foo : CharSequence by String(StringBuilder("xyzzy")) {
  }
}
```

Aside: `String` in Kotlin has no constructor that takes a String parameter. Odd, that.

Comment: Regarding the last sentence: the corresponding Java constructor lost its main use since version 7u6 (if I remember correctly, but it should be something in that range) and still exists there for backwards compatibility. Kotlin has no need to copy it.

Comment: Yes I realized that there's no need to use that constructor in the code above.. this is equivalent: `companion object Foo : CharSequence by "xyzzy"`